# Error Converting Varchar to int Passing Multiple Numbers in the Parameter

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure where I have a parameter called `@styleoffers`.

The parameter is a `dbo.Split`.

The parameter is a list of Style Offer keys that are associated with particular styles that are also a parameter that is a dbo,Split.

I also created a table that gathers all style numbers and their associated style keys, so that when a style offer is selected, only the associated style numbers are listed.

If an offer is not selected, the user can select multiple style numbers to pass through the parameter.

both parameters are declared as `varchar(max)`, to allow multiple selections.

The problem is when in preview mode in crystal reports, an error shows converting varchar to int.  I can't change the parameters to int, because of the split.

How do I get past this error?

Comment: What concrete database are you using? MySQL? Oracle? IBM DB2? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Something else? Please add a relevant tag!!

Comment: Seems like a problem with your crystal report, moreso than the database?

Comment: here is the stored procedure.  The problem is, I believe in the split on my parameter in the stored procedure,  Here is the SP and the parameter in question is @StyleOffers: